# Nosetests & Combined Coverage

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I have many projects that I'm programatically running:

`nosetest --with-coverage --cover-html-dir=happy-sauce/`

The problem is that for each project, the coverage module overwrites the index.html file, instead of appending to it.  Is there a way to generate a combined super-index.html file, that contains the results for all my projects?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't combine the HTML directories.  You can combine the .coverage data files, but you'll have to use coverage directly, rather than through nose:

```
$ nosetest --with-coverage proj1
$ mv .coverage .coverage.1
$ nosetest --with-coverage proj2
$ mv .coverage .coverage.2
$ coverage combine
(combines .coverage.1 and .coverage.2 into a new .coverage)
$ coverage html --directory=happy-sauce
```

Comment: I can't seem to get my `nosetest --with-coverage` to generate the .coverage file, is there a flag for this? (nosetests version 1.0.1)

Comment: It's always generated in the folder where nose is executed.

Answer (score 1):

`nosetests --with-coverage -i project1/*.py -i project2/*.py`